# Produce a file that has integers common to two large files containing integers

Tags: algorithm

Specifically, given two large files with 64-bit integers produce a file with integers that are present in both files and estimate the time complexity of your algorithm.

How would you solve this?

Comment: Are the files sorted? Can you sort them? How large, I assume you can't fit them into memory? Can you fit *one* of them into memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could a [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), then iterate over the sorted results keeping the matches .  Radix is O(DN), where D is the number of digits in the numbers.  The largest 64 bit number is 19 digits long, so the sort sort for 64 bit integers with a radix of 10 will run in about 19N, or O(N), and the search runs in O(N).  Thus this would run in O(N) time, where N is the number of integers in both files.

Comment: Do you mean that radix sort is linear ?! it has O(k*N) complexity, where k is NOT intependent from N. The complexity of radix sort is Ω(N*logN). For more details see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Comment: @Grigor: It is O(kN), which in the general case reduces to O(N*logN). In the case of 64 bit integers k=19, so this reduces to O(N).  I clarified my answer to point this out.

Comment: the "NOT independent" assumes all integers are distinct (which is not necessarily the case in this instance)

Comment: intersection of 2 sorted lists is easy, you just iterate through both of them as in a merge sort

Comment: @Ryan: You may not change one of the parameters to a constant. In this way, you can say that N < 10^20, so k*N < 19 * 10^20 and reduce O(k*N) to O(19*10^20) = O(1), which is completely wrong.

Comment: @Grigor: I'm not just changing a parameter to a constant.  I know the upper bound on one of the parameters, so I am substituting that.  In this case, the upper bound happens to be a constant.

Comment: @Nemo: "Suggesting radix sort for 64-bit numbers implies you have never actually implemented a radix sort" ??? Why? You don't need to have 2^64 buckets, just use LSD radix sort with 10 files, then re-merge after each step -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Least_significant_digit_radix_sorts

Comment: @Nemo: Good point.  He was only looking for an algorithm with good time complexity, so I sacraficed space.  You could write to files if you need to.

Comment: @Ryan: Yes, and that's what I say you may not do, because if so, you also know the upper bound of 64-bit integers, and your logic allows to reduce complexity to O(1)

Comment: @Grigor: I do know the upper bound on 64 bit integers: [2^64](http://www.google.com/search?q=2^64).  I **don't** know how many numbers are in the files... hence this must remain N.

Comment: @Grigor: there could be 2^92 integers in the files. The problem statement did not say whether the integers were distinct.

Comment: @Ryan: Have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Efficiency. Here the complexity is calculated considering exactly the same problem - sorting n integers with k or fewer digits. The result is Ω(n·log n)

Comment: @Jason:  I do not believe there are 2^92 bytes in all of the storage on the planet combined...

Comment: @Nemo: :-) Yeah, I couldn't remember what a reasonable number was.

Comment: @Nemo: Google allegedly processes 24 petabytes of data per day = approx 2^54. http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1327452.1327492

Comment: @Jason:  No worries.  I forgot the details of how a radix sort works :-)

Comment: @Grigor: I read that before posting my original answer. In the next section it explains: `An LSD radix sort operates in O(nk) time, where n is the number of keys, and k is the average key length.`

Comment: @Grigor: reread the wikipedia section (Radix_sort#Efficiency) you cited: "As an example, consider the ordering of a list of n *different* integers." (my emphasis).

Comment: @Grigor: The efficiency section also requires that comparisons be made to put the integers into buckets, but this could be done just as easily by hashing.  In the case of a small number of buckets (like 10), you could simply use the digit as an index into an array to find the bucket)

Comment: @Ryan... If you have sorted numbers then I wonder why didn't you use a binary search :)

Comment: @DHaram I didn't because it is faster to find the matches using a linear scan of both arrays at once (O(N) - similar to the merge step in a merge sort) than to do a log(N) search for each of the numbers in one of the arrays O(Nlog(N))

Answer (score 5):

I changed my mind; I actually like @Ryan's radix sort idea, except I would adapt it a bit for this specific problem.

Let's assume there are so many numbers that they do not fit in memory, but we have all the disk we want.  (Not unreasonable given how the question was phrased.)

Call the input files A and B.

So, create 512 new files; call them file A_0 through A_255 and B_0 through B_255.  File A_0 gets all of the numbers from file A whose high byte is 0.  File A_1 gets all of the numbers from file A whose high byte is 1.  File B_37 gets all the numbers from file B whose high byte is 37.  And so on.

Now all possible duplicates are in (A_0, B_0), (A_1, B_1), etc., and those pairs can be analyzed independently (and, if necessary, recursively).  And all disk accesses are reasonably linear, which should be fairly efficient.  (If not, adjust the number of bits you use for the buckets...)

This is still O(n log n), but it does not require holding everything in memory at any time.  (Here, the constant factor in the radix sort is log(2^64) or thereabouts, so it is not really linear unless you have a *lot* more than 2^64 numbers.  Unlikely even for the largest disks.)

[edit, to elaborate]

The whole point of this approach is that *you do not actually have to sort the two lists*.  That is, with this algorithm, at no time can you actually enumerate the elements of either list in order.

Once you have the files A_0, B_0, A_1, B_1, ..., A_255, B_255, you simply observe that no numbers in A_0 can be the same as any number in B_1, B_2, ..., B_255.  So you start with A_0 and B_0, find the numbers common to those files, append them to the output, then *delete* A_0 and B_0.  Then you do the same for A_1 and B_1, A_2 and B_2, etc.

To find the common numbers between A_0 and B_0, you just recurse...  Create file A_0_0 containing all elements of A_0 with *second* byte equal to zero.  Create file A_0_1 containing all elements of A_0 with second byte equal to 1.  And so forth.  Once all elements of A_0 and B_0 have been bucketed into A_0_0 through A_0_255 and B_0_0 through B_0_255, you can *delete* A_0 and B_0 themselves because you do not need them anymore.

Then you recurse on A_0_0 and B_0_0 to find common elements, deleting them as soon as they are bucketed...  And so on.

When you finally get down to buckets that only have one element (possibly repeated), you can immediately decide whether to append that element to the output file.

At no time does this algorithm consume more than 2+epsilon times the original space required to hold the two files, where epsilon is less than half a percent.  (Proof left as an exercise for the reader.)

I honestly believe this is the most efficient algorithm among all of these answers if the files are too large to fit in memory.  (As a simple optimization, you can fall back to the std::set solution if and when the "buckets" get small enough.)

Comment: wouldn't this create an excessively large number of files? (one reason why LSD radix sorts are used over MSD radix sorts)

Comment: @Jason: If the numbers are 64-bit and you know nothing else about them, how can you assume the high bytes are more likely to be zero than the low bytes?  As the question is phrased, LSD vs. MSD are equivalent.

Comment: @Nemo: LSD sort is a *stable* sort, so you can recombine the numbers and retain sortedness, then iterate w/o having to increase the # of buckets. The basic MSD sort in numerical order requires recursion and hence more buckets. However, if you just need a defined ordering, an iterated sort in MSD order (w/o recursion) would end up sorting the numbers in reverse-digit order and that's fine for uniqueness/intersection purposes, so your approach is valid if you don't care about numerical order.

Comment: @Jason:  Right, but the point of my answer is that for this problem you do not need to "recombine" the numbers at all (except to produce the final output file, which does not need to be sorted).  You can solve this problem without ever fully sorting the numbers at all; the buckets are enough.  So stability of the sort is irrelevant.

Comment: @Nemo: --confused-- How many buckets are we talking about? I get your point about divide-and-conquer techniques to intersect the partitions, that's a good idea (+1), but let's say we have n=2^40 numbers in each of the two original files. If duplicates are allowed, we could still have nearly 2^40 in one or more of the sub-files (de-duplicating requires sorting, I think), so there isn't a predefined point at which you can jump from external sorting to internal sorting. I get the sense that the upper bound  on the # of buckets could be fairly high.

Comment: ...in other words, how do you get around your "and, if necessary, recursively" comment, where instead of 2*256 buckets you might need 2*256*256 buckets, or 2*256*256*256 buckets

Comment: @Jason: I do not think you are following what I mean, because I did not explain it very well.  I have added an update to my answer.  The whole point is that you do not need to sort the numbers at all, which means you can delete buckets along the way as soon as you are done with them.  Please let me know whether my update clarifies things or not...

Answer (score 3):

Read integers from both files into two `set`s (this will take `O(N*logN)` time), then iterate over two sets and write common elements to output file(this will take `O(N)` time). Complexity summary - `O(N*logN)`.

***Note***: The iteration part will perform faster if we store integers into `vector`s and then sort them, but here we will use much more memory if there are many duplicates of integers inside the files.

***UPD***: You can also store in the memory only distinct integers from one of the files:

Read the values from the smaller files into a `set`. Then read values from the second files one by one. For each next number `x` check it's presence in the set with `O(logN)`. If it exists there, print it and remove it from the set to avoid printing it twice. Complexity remains `O(N*logN)`, but you use memory only necessary to store distinct integers from the smallest file.

Comment: Java Sets do that, with the [`retainAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) method. Intersection of sets.

Comment: seeing as how these are *large* files, I don't think this can be relied upon

Comment: I assume that both files are larger than the physical memory available, so you can't form a set with the smaller of two files and keep it in memory. I think that a better way(acc. to mem. constraints) would be to take some part of file in mem. and then iterate one by one in second file finding if its there, if present then store it in out file, delete it from both files. When no matches occur then all elements are distinct, then you can store them directly. Complexity ~ O(N1*N2*logk) , k is the size of maximum available set.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the files are too large to fit into memory, use an *external* [least-significant-digit (LSD) radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Least_significant_digit_radix_sorts) on each of the files, then iterate through both files to find the intersection:

---

external LSD sort on base N (N=10 or N=100 if the digits are in a string format, N=16/32/64 if in binary format):

Create N temporary files (0 - N-1). Iterate through the input file. For each integer, find the rightmost digit in base N, and append that integer to the temporary file corresponding to that digit.

Then create a new set of N temporary files, iterate through the previous set of temporary files, find the 2nd-to-the-rightmost digit in base N (prepending 0s where necessary), and append that integer to the new temporary file corresponding to that digit. (and delete the previous set of temporary files)

Repeat until all the digits have been covered. The last set of temporary files contains the integers in sorted order. (Merge if you like into one file, otherwise treat the temporary files as one list.)

---

Finding the intersection:

Iterate through the sorted integers in each file to produce a pair of iterators that point to the current integer in each file. For each iterator, if the numbers match, append to an output list, and advance both iterators. Otherwise, for the smaller number, throw it away and advance the iterator for that file. Stop when either iterator ends.

(This outputs duplicates where there are input duplicates. If you want to remove duplicates, then the "advance the iterator" step should advance the iterator until the next larger number appears or the file ends.)